# Upgrading Postgres on Heroku from 9.2 to 9.3?

Tags: database, postgresql, heroku

I would like to use some `PLV8` features available in `9.3` in my application. The production database is currently on `9.2.5`. Is there a good way to move to `9.3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current method for updating is to take advantage of Heroku Postgres' pgbackups addon. To do this you would:

```
heroku addons:add pgbackups
heroku pgbackups:capture
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:plan_here
heroku pgbackups:restore...
```

You can find more thorough steps on their devcenter https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups

If you're on one of the new hobby plans Heroku is rolling out a more seamless upgrade path directly with customers. You can reach out to them directly to get in the queue for this.

Comment: Are you sure that works for version upgrades? I have done what you have mentioned when I migrated from starter plan to the production tier. Moreover the link you have provided mentions I should use followers while upgrading between production tiers. And as far as I understand, followers can't be created of a version different from that of the primary database.

Comment: Craig works on the Heroku Postgres team - it's an authoritative answer :)

Comment: Should have checked that :) Thanks!

Comment: Version upgrades require a dump and restore currently. There will be a mechanism soon for upgrading across versions without a full dump restore, but only on non-hobby databases.

Comment: Question for @CraigKerstiens: just got the forced upgrade required notice for a number of my databases on the old plans (Fugu/Kappa) and my attempts to upgrade them using the follower-based methods are failing (I get "Standard tier plans only support Postgres version 9.3. To provision a 9.1 database, use one of these legacy plans: crane, kappa, ronin, fugu, ika, zilla, baku, mecha"). Is there any way to get into this new upgrade mechanism this weekend (as I'd love to do it during my customer scheduled maintenance window).

Comment: @CraigKerstiens Any idea what timeframe for this mechanism? We need to upgrade but it would be over 30 minutes of maintenance page downtime with this flow! Huge impact on our customers and I'm sure there are heroku accounts much larger than us.

Comment: @Forrest this is now available via a plugin, but only encouraged for databases over 20GB. You can find more on it at https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras under the pg:upgrade command.

Comment: The `heroku pgbackups:transfer DATABASE new_one` command worked great for us - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras#pgbackupstransfer